# Потеря рядов при pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

Прошу помощи со следующей проблемой:
при использовании pandas.read_csv теряются строки данных.
Мои действия пошагово:

```
# читаем данные в датафрейм   
import pandas as pan   
d = pan.read_csv('card.txt', sep = '|', encoding = 'cp1251')
print len(d)
```

Проверяем результат:

```
#читаем содержимое файла
import codecs
fh = codecs.open('card.txt','r', encoding = 'cp1251')

text = list()
#делим на строки
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    text.append(line)

print len(text)
```

Получаем len(text) - len(d) = 214000

С чем может быть связана эта проблема? Буду очень признательна за помощь.

Comment: Если в файле нет заголовка, то можно указать header=None при чтении csv. Но скорее всего ошибка в данных, если добавить error_bad_lines=False в read_csv, то можно будет увидеть строки, которые не были прочитаны из-за ошибок. Вероятнее всего, в каких-то строках количество элементов не соответствует длине заголовка.